# Function Model in PL/SQL context

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm stuck in function model choices.

What are the rules of thumb with regard to choosing a pass_by_value or pass_by_reference function?

For example:

- When you want produce a result by consuming the input.
- When you need to couple behavior of the calling and called program units.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What exactly are you asking?  Show an example or something.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` parameters are always passed `by reference`, always, it's their default passing method and cannot be changed.

`OUT` and `IN OUT` parameters are passed  `by value`, by default, but by including `NOCOPY` hint in the declaration of a formal `IN OUT` or `OUT` parameter you can instruct Oracle to pass an actual parameter `by reference`. But, including that `NOCOPY` hint does not guarantee success. The PL/SQL optimizer might choose to ignore it and pass an actual parameter by value.

Unless there is a really gigantic, *not empty* variable of a composite data type, whether it's a collection or an instance of an abstract data type, should be passed in a stored procedure, modified there, and returned back to the invoker, and you absolutely do not care about whether an actual parameter would retain its pre-invocation value if execution of your stored procedure fails somewhere in the middle with an unhandled exception, there is really no need to use `NOCOPY` hint.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you are worrying about the wrong thing at the wrong time. Unless you ***know*, based on *extensive testing*** that there's a problem which can be traced to the parameter-passing mechanism, go with the defaults. Concentrate on making your design as clean and as normalized as possible.

Optimization Rules:

1. The best time to optimize is never (because it means there isn't a problem - move on).
2. The second-best time is when you have a real performance problem.
3. The **WORST** time to optimize is at design time. To quote Donald Knuth, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Corollaries to this are:

   - It ain't broke 'til it's broke.
   - You can't improve what you haven't measured.
   - Make it run. Make it run right. Make it run right **fast** - optimization is literally the *last* thing you should be doing.

YMMV.

Share and enjoy.